# How to use a Reader type encoded with continuation passing style

Tags: haskell, continuation-passing, higher-rank-types, scott-encoding

I was under the impression that every value of type `a` can be described with a rank-2 polymorphic type `newtype Id a = Id {runId :: forall r. (a -> r) -> r }` in continuation passing style. So I derived the following type to define the `Reader` accordingly:

```
newtype Reader e a = Reader {runReader :: forall r. ((e -> a) -> r) -> r}
```

Then I tried to construct a value of this type and run it:

```
reader f = Reader (\k -> k f) -- where is f's argument?
runReader (reader id) -- what is the 2nd argument?
```

Provided that `Reader`'s encoding in CPS and its type are valid, how would I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reader f = Reader (\k -> k f) -- where is f's argument?
```

We don't have to pass a second argument now. This is very similar to the regular `data Reader e a = Reader (e->a)` and `reader f = Reader f` which do not involve a second argument.

```
runReader (reader id) -- what is the 2nd argument?
```

The general equation is

```
runReader (reader f) k = k f
```

so,

```
runReader (reader f) id x = id f x = f x
```

You can use `f = id` (which acts like `ask` in the real reader monad), but don't confuse it with the other `id` which is provided as a continuation `k`, and which recovers the original `f`.

Comment: I think you want `id f x = f x`, not `id f x = x`.

Comment: It's probably useful to define a helper `runReader' = flip runReader id` to get rid of the continuation.